# Squid proxy configuration for client SSL termination

Tags: security, ssl, proxy, squid

I would like to get the recommendation on how to configure Squid (latest version) with client SSL termination.

The requirement is to provide proxy access to the internet for the client who has no ability to install a custom CA certificate.

Following the documentation [here](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS#Encrypted_browser-Squid_connection), it is possible to use HTTPS for the browser-proxy connection the same way as HTTP.

However, the only way to [achieve that](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/SslBumpExplicit) is to use SSL Interception with self-signed CA certificate, which cannot work in my case.

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to replace the client-to-server encryption offered by HTTPS with client-to-proxy-encryption followed by proxy-to-server encryption without a client needing to trust the proxy. If this would work it would make HTTPS fundamentally insecure since every man-in-the-middle attacker could just do this. So fortunately it will not work.

Comment: Agree, but I am not looking for MITM (or SSL intercept). Squid supports SSL tunneling in addition to intercept. What I am looking for is the way to tunnel the client SSL connect, where TLS is the first layer of encapsulation, as oppose to plain HTTP.

Comment: @Bigmyx: It was not clear for me from your question that you want to have a non-intercepting HTTP proxy which gets access by HTTPS. In this case what's wrong with just using `https_port` instead of `http_port` in this case and configure a proxy specific certificate (trusted by the client and issued for the domain/IP of the proxy as configured by the client) used on this port with `tls-cert=...`. Of course the client must support accessing a HTTP proxy over HTTPS in the first place which not all do.

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!